# How to pass Outputs from One Module to another?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have two modules.

1. one is called `module-azure-vnet`
2. second is called `module-azure-vm-instance-zabbix-proxy`

I want to pass Outputs from module `module-azure-vnet` to module `module-azure-vm-instance-zabbix-proxy`. First module is working properly, but second needs inputs for subnet, security group and route.

main.tf

```
module "module-azure-vnet-dtap" {
  source = "/Users/username/project/module-azure-vnet-dtap"
}

variable "subnets_id_wan" {}

module "module-azure-vm-instance-zabbix-proxy" {
  source = "/Users/username/project/module-azure-vm-instance-zabbix-proxy"
  azurerm_subnet = "${module.module-azure-vnet-dtap.azurerm_subnet.wan.id}"
}
```

> Error: resource 'azurerm_network_interface.no_public_ip' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_subnet.wan' referenced in variable azurerm_subnet.wan.id
>
> Error: resource 'azurerm_network_security_rule.security_rule_default' config: unknown resource 'azurerm_network_security_group.wan' referenced in variable azurerm_network_security_group.wan.name
>
> Error: module "module-azure-vm-instance-zabbix-proxy": "azurerm_subnet" is not a valid argument

In module `module-azure-vnet-dtap`

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "wan" {
  count                     = "${var.enable_wan_subnet ? 1 : 0}"
  provider                  = "azurerm.base"
  name                      = "${format("%s-%s-%s", var.environment_name, "WAN", "Subnet")}"
  virtual_network_name      = "${azurerm_virtual_network.this.name}"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.this.name}"
  address_prefix            = "${cidrsubnet(var.cidr_block,5,count.index)}"
  route_table_id            = "${azurerm_route_table.wan.id}"
  network_security_group_id = "${azurerm_network_security_group.wan.id}"
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "wan" {
  count               = "${var.enable_wan_subnet ? 1 : 0}"
  provider            = "azurerm.base"
  name                = "${format("%s-%s", var.environment_name, "WAN-Subnet-Security-Group")}"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.this.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.this.name}"
}

output "subnets_id_wan" {
  value = "${azurerm_subnet.wan.*.id}"

  depends_on = [
    "azurerm_subnet.wan",
  ]
}
```

Comment: Try commenting out the `module "module-azure-vm-instance-zabbix-proxy"` block and then run `terraform init && terraform refresh && terraform show | less` and look at all the output names and values to see if the module is outputting the correct value or if you're passing in the correct output to the zabbix proxy module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found solution myself, here is the whole structure what is needed in order to connect two modules.

set variables in VNET module example:

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
      default     = "default_resource_group"
      }

      variable "region_name" {
      default     = "ukwest"
      }
```

declare outputs:

```
output "security_groups_id_wan" {
      value = "${element(concat(azurerm_network_security_group.wan.*.id, list("")),0)}"

        depends_on = [
          "azurerm_subnet.wan",
          ]
      }
```

you need variables in zabbix proxy module to receive values>

```
variable "resource_group_name" {
        default = ""
        }
        variable "resource_group_location" {
        default = ""
        }
```

and in external folder where is the main.tf for modules>

```
module "module-azure-vm-instance-zabbix-proxy" {
        source = "/Users/username/project/module-azure-vm-instance-zabbix-proxy"
        resource_group_name = "${module.module-azure-vnet-dtap.resource_group_name}"
        resource_group_location = "${module.module-azure-vnet-dtap.resource_group_location}"
        subnets_id_wan = "${module.module-azure-vnet-dtap.subnets_id_wan}"
        security_groups_name = "${module.module-azure-vnet-dtap.security_groups_name_dmz}"
        environment_name = "${module.module-azure-vnet-dtap.environment_name}"
      }

      module module-azure-vnet-dtap {
        source = "/Users/username/project/module-azure-vnet-dtap"
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

you should reference output like this:

```
"${module.MODULE_NAME.OUTPUT_NAME}"
```

in your case it should be:

```
"${module.module-azure-vnet-dtap.subnets_id_wan}"
```

also, you can only access outputs, not resources from the module (afaik).

Comment: Hi,

Got same errors after changing azurerm_subnet.wan.id to subnets_id_wan